# different results of 2 sample kolmogorov-smirnov gof matlab

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

I made a GOF test in matlab, but two sample Kolmogorov Smirnov tests gave me opposite results. 
In matlab I used this code

```
file=importdata('all_subj_1file.xls','\t');
[ill1]=xlsread('all_subj_1file.xls','ill1','B2:E1608');
ill1_frac=ill1(:,2);
[a,b]=gamfit(ill1_frac);
y=gamrnd(a(1),a(2),1607,1); %same length gamma
[h, p, ks2stat]=kstest2(ill1_frac, y)
```

But from time to time I get different `p` and `ks2stat` too (probably, because I generate new gamrnd each time I run a code).
**The question is** how do I choose a result of Kolmogorov-Smirnov? Should I run the code many times and choose the one I like the most? But they are opposite (like Ho or H1 level of deviation).

Answer (score 0):

The one sample Kolmogorov Smirnov test should be used instead of two sample KS test in order to get GOF of a theoretical distribution.